# Add sql user defined function as a property to dbml

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have a user defined function in sql server that returns a string. I want to add this as a property to my class in linq to sql dbml file. My Class represents a view in sql server. (Note, I don't want to add this UDF to the view)

I've tried to create a property manually and then assign the source as the name of my UDF in sql server. Doesn't like this and errors.

Is what I'm doing possible?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can only map a client method defined on a class to a user-defined function by using the FunctionAttribute attribute.

But you can wrap your function in your class with property

```
CREATE FUNCTION Test(@string varchar(100))
RETURNS varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN "Test"
END

[Function(Name = "Test", IsComposable = true)]
[return: Parameter(DbType = "VarChar(100)")]

public string Test([Parameter(Name = "string",
    DbType = "VarChar(100)")] string @string)
{
    return ((string)(this.ExecuteMethodCall(this,
        ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())),
        @string).ReturnValue));
}
```